# on DOM changes, need to fire a function, jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

the title is explaining problem i have pretty well. After ajax success elements are loaded on page again! All my manipulations have to be done again! But i cant seem to figure this out.

Here is the code:

```
function fixed_trigger(){
  if($("#resource_fixed").prop("checked")){
    $("div[data-name='fixed_from']").show();
    $("div[data-name='fixed_to']").show();
  } else {
    $("div[data-name='fixed_from']").hide();
    $("div[data-name='fixed_to']").hide();
  }
}

function defaults(){
  if($("#resource_formula_type").val() != undefined || null || "" ){
    var types = $("#resource_formula_type").val().split(",");
    for(var i=0; i<types.length; i++){
      $("#formula_type option[value='"+types[i]+"']").prop("selected", true);
    }
  }
  fixed_trigger();
}

$(document).ready(defaults());
$(document).on("change", "#resource_fixed", function(){
  fixed_trigger();
});
$(document).on("change", "#formula_type", function(){
  var string = $(this).val().toString();
  $("#resource_formula_type").val(string);
});
```

On document ready i trigger a function which hides some elements, but after form is loaded again i need to trigger `defaults()` again which i cant figure out how. Please help. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i figured it out. Probably nobody would have helped me here, CMS which was created by 3th party for our projects have created that CMS feature, method is to bind listeners on elements and after ajax loads content if on of thous elements or children of thous elements is changed than it triggers. i stack this feature on body and it works just fine now.

```
$("body").on("contentloaded", function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(document).ready(defaults());
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(defaults);
```

---

You don't need to put `()` with the function name there in the `ready` callback.

Comment: thx for the tip, tho that does not change anything. It worked on first document ready with or without (), but still not working after DOM changed!

Comment: would you plz shed light on your form thing.

Comment: that could be complicated, because form is generated automatically by CMS, and backend is ruby, so templates are used to create edit/new forms using activerecord models!

Comment: does not change a thing! :/